# Is it possible to access a modified query string in a RewriteCond *after* applying a RewriteRule?

Tags: rewrite, regex, rewritecond

**Is it possible to access a modified query string in a RewriteCond *after* applying a RewriteRule?**

What I'm trying is to apply ...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?id=([^&]+)&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/app\.jsp$ /app/%2?%1%3 [R=302]
```

... to rewrite following urls into "nice" ones. That already works, but for (2) and (3) there are still unneccessary trailing "?" and "%" chars that I'd like to remove:

```
/app.jsp?id=123&b=1 -> /app/123?b=1    (1)
/app.jsp?id=123     -> /app/123?       (2)
/app.jsp?b=1&id=123 -> /app/123?b=1&   (3)
```

My idea is to add additional conditional RewriteRule's to remove the trailing "?" and "%" chars from the *modified* query string but I don't know how to access the latter within subsequent RewriteCond's. Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a simple solution myself:

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}       ^()id=([^&]+)(.*)$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond \?%{QUERY_STRING}  ^(\?.*)&id=([^&]+)(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^/app\.jsp$ /app/%2%1%3                     [R=302,QSD,L]
```

Rewrite results:

```
/app.jsp?id=123&b=1      -> /app/123?b=1       (1)
/app.jsp?id=123          -> /app/123           (2)
/app.jsp?b=1&id=123      -> /app/123?b=1       (3)
/app.jsp?b=1&id=123&d=2  -> /app/123?b=1&d=2   (4)
```

Some remarks:

- successfully tested with Apache Tomcat's Rewrite Valve (see *https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html*) for urls like *https://example.com/my_webapp/app.jsp*
- should work with Apache httpd as well, possibly with ^app instead of ^/app in the *RewriteRule*
- some .htaccess testers like *https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/* don't seem to accept TestStrings like *?%{QUERY_STRING}*. Such cases should therefore be tested directly with Tomcat (or httpd).